# Ruby Rails - Querying Records with Enumerations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, mapping

There is a table `Fans` with columns `id` and `color` which uses enumerations so that `{ "blue": 0, "yellow": 1 }` and the db just stores the integer values.

```
Fan.all.map {|fan| fan.attributes}
```

returns an array of hashes where the color is still in the integer form.  How do I get the array of hashes where the color field is mapped into the text?

Answer (score 0):

`Fan.colors` will give you the hash: `{ "blue": 0, "yellow": 1 }`

and,

```
my_fan = Fan.find(123)
my_fan[:color] # Returns the integer value of color
```

So, to get the color text, you can build a hash like this:

```
new_color_hash = { '0': "blue", "1": "yellow" }
```

which is trivial (just swapping the keys with values in the original enum hash)

Then, when you loop through the `Fan` attributes, just call:

```
new_color_hash[my_fan[:color].to_s]
```

to get the text representation of the color of this particular `Fan` instance.

This will work, although this is not a very good looking implementation.